# I want to insert Date like 24-05-2010 in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I am using C# code for inserting record and datetimepicker control for Date
I want to insert Date like 24-05-2010 in MySQL Database
What Datatype i have to use for that in MySQL table

and how to right insert query for to insert date?

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't want it :)
Are you really concerned of the format in which data will be *stored*?

I am sure you want to use `2010-05-24` format and date `date` field type.

While if you want to *display* it back in your own format, you can use a `date_format()` function in your SELECT query

Comment: Yeah, ISO-8601 dates only. Not UK style dates, or US style dates. Just ISO-8601.

Comment: i am developing window application using visual studio and c# i want to insert date in Mysql database table which having datatype date

using datetimepicker control of visual studio

i wrote insertquery like this (insert into table name values('"+ datetimepicker.value + "')

it give me following error

ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.47-community]Incorrect datetime value: '01-06-2010 00:00:00' for column 'Date' at row 1

can any one resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DATE datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html), which by default will retrieve it as 2010-05-24 when you get the value as a string. If you need that specific format you mentioned, you can either store it as a [VARCHAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)(10) or use a function (e.g. [`DATE_FORMAT('%d-%m-%y')`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)) when getting the value from the table.

Comment: i am developing window application using visual studio and c# i want to insert date in Mysql database table which having datatype date

using datetimepicker control of visual studio

i wrote insertquery like this (insert into table name values('"+ datetimepicker.value + "')

it give me following error

ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.47-community]Incorrect datetime value: '01-06-2010 00:00:00' for column 'Date' at row 1

can any one resolve this problem